# Is there a way to force "Display over other apps" Android 10 Go?

Tags: android

I have a Hisense U963 running Android 10 Go edition

I am trying to install Bolt Driver

I cannot complete the install as when I try to select the required "Display over other apps" is returns with "Feature not available" "This feature has been turned off because it slows down your phone"

While I understand and accept that the U963 has a meagre 1GB RAM, I have run the Bolt Driver app on several phones running Android 4.4, 6, etc with the same or less RAM capacity.

Am I being naive to think that the OS has the ability, just someone somewhere wanted to be clever and give a headache to millions of app users globally that require overlay?

Many thanks.

Comment: A Non PC Solution is available [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246036/how-can-i-enable-display-over-other-apps-in-nokia-1-4-when-feature-is-disabled).

Answer (score 3):

**YES**, someone somewhere wanted to be clever, and that one is Google. There are thousands of people who find this neat "feature" infuriating on the android support forum.

There is a workaround, though, *for specific APKs of which you know the package name*, and I found it in [this reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/m3tu3n/comment/hxb3aqb/). But you need to use `adb`, hence have an `adb` that works with your device, which might or might not be an easy task. For my *KT1006* device (a cheap tablet from a chinese company called "Kid's Tablet") I just used the `adb` I had lying around (the one I installed from the Lenovo site to use it with my other tablet, which is a Lenovo) and it accidentally works fine.

Basically, it boils down to:

```
adb shell pm grant <package-name> android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

You can get the `package-name` in a number of ways, but the dumbest and easiest is looking up the app you want to unlock in the play store and check out the `id` query field in the url.

e.g. for *Touch Protector* (which is a *must-have* app on tablets that are literally designed for childrens), the play store url looks like this:

> play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=**biz.obake.team.touchprotector**&gl=US

You take the `id` from there, and (provided you can get an `adb` shell) just type this into your terminal and you're done.

```
adb shell pm grant biz.obake.team.touchprotector android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`
```

Answer (score -1):

Not trying to be a thread-necromancer or anything, but I ran into this same problem and it was a massive headache.

My solution was barely different, but that can be crippling sometimes, so...I'm going to contribute to this thread to help anyone else with the same problem.

I was trying to install a legitimate parental monitor on my kids' crappy phones, which were running Android 10 Go.  (The system info said they were just running 10, not 10 Go, which is different and has the aforementioned problem.)

I followed the tutorial here to get it to work:

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

It looks like the original response (THANK YOU again!) was able to run the terminal on the phone. I have no idea how you did that. I had to plug mine into my computer to run the terminal from there. (To make things even more niche, I happen to be running Ubuntu Linux, version 22.04.)

I was able to use Android Studio to help troubleshoot the requisite USB connection (because wifi adb didn't work).

Then, in order to find the correct package name, I had to go to the Google Play store to find a Package Name Viewer (I used the one that was linked in the original Reddit thread, from csing).  Turned out the URL in the play store had extra characters that weren't needed at the end.

And so my final terminal command looked like this:

```
$SomeUserGuy:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ adb -s <DEVICENAME> shell pm grant <PACKAGENAME> android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

I had to use this command to see the device name to use:

```
adb devices -l
```

The result was a crazy long string of meaningless alphanumeric characters.

But like you said, it instantly worked.  The terminal didn't say "And it worked!" or anything, but when I checked the app's details on the device, it showed that it indeed had been granted permission to be displayed over the system alert.

Here's hoping that these other developers make things easier for users in the future.